# How can I reset the sidebar elements in VSC to the default places?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I moved by fault the location of the history, search, git, ... in sidebar and I can't find a way to get the sidebar to the default.

Is there a button to reset their elements location to default?

My current faulty elements locations:

[image: visual studio code sidebar]

Comment: use the context menu and select **Reset Location** or command **Reset View Locations**

Answer (score 67):

To reset sidebar icons, you can open the commands textbox with CTRL+SHIFT+P and then enter the commmand **> Reset View Locations**

Comment: It's CTRL+SHIFT+P

Comment: My Live Share extension icon vanished from the "primary sidebar".  This restored the icon to the primary sidebar, and its entry to the primary sidebar right-click menu.

Answer (score 1):

And if you accidentally hidden your bar in Visual Studio, you can make it visible again like this:

**Code > Settings... > Settings > Workbench > Appearance > ActivityBar: Visible**

and check the checkbox there:
[image]

Answer (score -6):

1、you can reorder the icon by drag & drop the sidebar icon

Comment: Sorry I'm downvoting this answer because the OP asks for which button to press to reset the sidebar elements completely. Dragging and dropping the sidebar icon surely can solve the problem but it's a tedious process, and it is not a convenient solution the OP is looking for

Comment: I don't know the old places